# How to call a Stored Procedure from another Stored Procedure in mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Can I do that because it call from function if i use a normal form such as xxx() in mysql? please show me how to do it,thx.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Stored procedure capabilities are RDBMS-specific.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server it is plain vanilla `exec proc` statement, here is sql server syntax

```
create procedure prYourProc
as

-- exec other proc
exec prSomeOtherProc

-- to get return value
declare @var int
exec @var = prSomeOtherProc
```

Answer (score 0):

PROCEDURE 1

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Proc1;
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc1()
BEGIN
  CALL Proc2();
END
```

PROCEDURE 2

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Proc2;
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc2()
BEGIN
  SELECT ColumnName  FROM table2;
END
```